# How to get a specific part of a string in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, split

I'm struggeling to find an elegant way to split strings to a specific part. I have strings in such formats:

```
some text of any length (need)
some text of any length (need-notneed)
some text of any length (notneed) (need)
some text of any length (notneed) (need-notneed)
```

All I need is the part with the word **need**.

**need** can be of 3 to 5 characters long.
These are things I can rely on:

- Directly before **need** there's always a **(**
- Directly after **need** there's always either a **)** or a **-** (any text after and including - should be cut off as well)

I hope I have described it well...
Sorry in case my English is not the best
Greetings from Vienna

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer using the code provided by Daniel, you can accept his answer as the one which solved your problem / provided a solution. It's a way to show appreciation to someone who helped you as well as will help others in the future with a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [**switch -regex**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.1#syntax).  We can use the regex pattern below to match the text you need.

> Pattern - `(?<=\()\S{3,5}(?=[-\)])`
>
> - Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\()` (Assert that the Regex below matches)
>
>   - `\(` matches the character `(`
> - `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
> - `{3,5}` matches the previous token between 3 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - Positive Lookahead `(?=[-\)])` (Assert that the Regex below matches)
>
>   - `[-\)]` will match either a `-` or `)`

**Code**

```
# some data to work with
$text = @'
some text of any length (need)
some text of any length (need-notneed)
some text of any length (notneed) (need)
some text of any length (notneed) (need-notneed)
some text of any length (RTX)
some text of any length (EOWD-notneed)
some text of any length (notneed) (12345)
some text of any length (notneed) (D.D03-notneed)
some text without any match
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# regex pattern that matches you requirement
$pattern = '(?<=\()\S{3,5}(?=[-\)])'

$results = switch -Regex ($text) {
    $pattern {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            String = $_
            Match  = $Matches[0]
        }
    }
    Default { }
}
```

```
PS > $results

String                                            Match
------                                            -----
some text of any length (need)                    need
some text of any length (need-notneed)            need
some text of any length (notneed) (need)          need
some text of any length (notneed) (need-notneed)  need
some text of any length (RTX)                     RTX
some text of any length (EOWD-notneed)            EOWD
some text of any length (notneed) (12345)         12345
some text of any length (notneed) (D.D03-notneed) D.D03
```

```
PS > $results.Match

need
need
need
need
RTX
EOWD
12345
D.D03
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel! Thanks a lot for that great solution! 
I just have a Problem when staring with a single string instead of an array.
For example $text = "some text of any length (need-notneed)". It seems that it matches than the first occurance of need. Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh I see - it comes to a doubel match when the text in the first brackets is lower or equal than 5. Chec it out there: https://regex101.com/r/ZpOx3v/1

Comment: Yeah, it does.  If you have any "(notneed)" that are 3-5 characters long it will also match those.  Do you have any way to differentiate these from the "(need)"s?

Comment: `(?:.*)(?<=\()(\S{3,5})(?=[-\)])` might work better if the (need) always comes after the (notneed).  Since the wanted match will now be in the 1st capturing group you'll also have to change `$Matches[0]` to `$Matches[1]`   https://regex101.com/r/rWZEdL/1

Answer (score 0):

**That's the perfect pattern! Thanks Daniel!** I will probably need hours to understand this regex ;-) But it works great:

```
$text = @'
some text of any length (need)
some text of any length (need-notneed)
some text of any length (notneed) (need)
some text of any length (notneed) (need-notneed)
some text of any length (RTX)
some text of any length (EOWD-notneed)
some text of any length (notneed) (12345)
some text of any length (notneed) (D.D03-notneed)
some text without any match
some text of any length (notn) (need)
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# regex pattern that matches your requirement
$pattern = '(?:.*)(?<=\()(\S{3,5})(?=[-\)])'

$results = switch -Regex ($text) {
    $pattern {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            String = $_
            Match  = $Matches[1]
        }
    }
    Default { }
}
```

Will result in those matches:

```
PS> $results                 
                                     
String                                            Match
------                                            -----
some text of any length (need)                    need 
some text of any length (need-notneed)            need 
some text of any length (notneed) (need)          need 
some text of any length (notneed) (need-notneed)  need 
some text of any length (RTX)                     RTX  
some text of any length (EOWD-notneed)            EOWD 
some text of any length (notneed) (12345)         12345
some text of any length (notneed) (D.D03-notneed) D.D03
some text of any length (notn) (need)             need
```

**See especially the last match that matches now correctly!** It also makes no difference if started with an array or a single string - both matches correctly.

Thanks again!